# add custom parameters in $routeprovider when route is changed

Tags: angularjs, routes

Hi i want trying to add some custom parameters in my routes.js to initiate when route is changed but its not working. i have created a function which will load my external js fill having my controller. i want to load it using resolve and want to define the path in route to which it will load 
here is my code

```
function loadScript(url, type, charset) {
    if (type === undefined)
        type = 'text/javascript';
    if (url) {
        var script = document.querySelector("script[src*='" + url + "']");
        if (!script) {
            var heads = document.getElementsByTagName("footer");
            if (heads && heads.length) {
                var head = heads[0];
                if (head) {
                    script = document.createElement('script');
                    script.setAttribute('src', url);
                    script.setAttribute('type', type);
                    if (charset)
                        script.setAttribute('charset', charset);
                    head.appendChild(script);
                }
            }
        }
        return script;
    }
}

var rajApp = angular.module('rajApp');
rajApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$controllerProvider',
    function ($routeProvider, $controllerProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
                when('/challan', {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/challan/challan.html',
                    controller: 'challanController',
                    scripts: ["scripts/challan/challanController.js"],
                    resolve: {
                        getChallan: function (rajServices) {
                            return rajServices.getChallanDetails();
                        },
                        module:function(){
                            $route.scripts
                        }

                   }
                }).
                otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/login',
                    templateUrl: 'templates/login/index.html',
                    controller: 'loginController',
                });

    }])
```

Comment: Looks like you want some module loader, like RequireJS.

Comment: nops i have created my own loadscript()